# Cancel IF method

Tags: c#

I have one problem. In my app I have `RadioButtons`, and `CheckButtons`, it is a Survey.

When someone skips one question, and leaves it blank, I have this message to popup:

```
 if(pao.Odgovor == "")
 {
      var messageDialog = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Morate popuniti sva polja.");
      await messageDialog.ShowAsync();
 }
```

I want to somehow after this "await" application to stop, and the user must fill up all fields. I tried with `return`, `return false`, `break` but nothing helps.

Also, it's a `Void` method.

Thx :)

Comment: The full code for your function (and the function that calls it) will help you get a better answer ... it looks like the code you have already posted will function as you expect, and therefore it must be the calling function that continues execution.

Comment: cant you just validate all your fields

Comment: Some reformatting and typos.

Answer (score 0):

In your case i would create a List with all questions which must be answered. The suvery is finished if the list with questions is empty. If one question is not answerd correctly, it will not be removed from the list. If you still iterate from question to question, the user has to answer it before the next question comes.

If you work with an First-In-First-Out list, you can be sure the questions will always be in a correct order.

Hope this will help.